# Postgres (SQL) Find Total Days Not Reserved

Tags: sql, postgresql

Ok say I have a table called bookings

```
id (PK)
class (int FK)
name (varchar 64)
start_date (timestamp)
end_date (timestamp)
...etc
```

For the year there are a number of booking what I'm looking for is the total number days a reservation was active. For example Jan 01 to Jan 05 and Jan 10 to Jan 12 would be total of 7 days it would exclude from Jan 06 to Jan 09...  apply this for XX months.

Comment: Which column represents reservation code or something like that? Is it class?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that **class** is the indicator of reservation. So this query will return total days reserved for last 12 months.

```
select class, sum(end_date-start_date)
from table
where start_date between current_date + (-12::int || ' month')::interval and 
current_date
group by class
```